# how can I prove that $\sqrt[7] 2$ does not belong to the set $\Bbb Q( \sqrt[7] 3)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to prove that  $\sqrt[7]{2}$  does not belong to the set $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[7] 3)$.

How can I express a set $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[7] 3)$?

Is it $\Bbb Q( \sqrt[7] 3) =\left\{ a + b\sqrt[7] 3 + c(\sqrt[7] 3)^2 + d(\sqrt[7] 3)^3 + e(\sqrt[7] 3)^4 + f(\sqrt[7] 3)^5+g(\sqrt[7] 3)^6\right\}$ ?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks for editing :)

Answer (score 1):

As lhf said, when you show $\sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$, your problem is fixed. We suppose that $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$. We have that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ is a $2$-dimensional vector space with base $\{1 , \sqrt{3}\}$. Then there exist $a , b \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\sqrt{2} = a + b \sqrt{3}$; so $2 = a^2 + 3 b^2 + 2 a b \sqrt{3}$; as $2 \in \mathbb{Q}$, we have $2 a b = 0$, then $a = 0$ or $b = 0$. On the one hand, if $a = 0$, we have that $2 = 3 b^2$, so $\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}} = b \in \mathbb{Q}$, and it cannot happen; on the other hand, if $b = 0$, then $2 = a^2$ and that implies $\sqrt{2} = a \in \mathbb{Q}$, which also cannot happen.

Comment: From the comment on the other answer you'll see the question wasn't properly asked.

Comment: I do not understand how that proves $\sqrt[7] 2$ does not belong to the set $\Bbb Q( \sqrt[7] 3)$?